# multiples join provocan que el valor de sum se duplique

Tags: mysql, join

tengo la siguiente consulta la cual trae todos los datos correctamente a excepción de dos sum, los cuales muestran su valor duplicado, ambos sum depende de un join a otra tabla donde comparten el mismo campo, el cual es el sku, la consulta es la siguiente:

```
        select productos.nombre,productos.sku,productos.descuento,productos.foto_referencia,productos.precio, 
        CAST(productos.precio-(productos.precio*(productos.descuento/100)) as int) as totalaPagar, 
    ofertas_expirables.fecha_expiracion, concat(categorias.url,"?byType=",secciones.id) as url, 
secciones.nombre as nombre_seccion, COALESCE(sum(detalle_ordencompra.cantidad_producto),0) as vendidos ,COALESCE(sum(sp.stock),0) as stock
                from `ofertas_expirables`
                left join `productos` on `ofertas_expirables`.`sku_producto` = `productos`.`sku`
                
                left join `stock_productos` as `sp` on `ofertas_expirables`.`sku_producto` = `sp`.`sku_producto`
                left join `detalle_ordencompra` on `ofertas_expirables`.`sku_producto` = detalle_ordencompra.sku_producto
                
                left join `secciones` on `productos`.`id_seccion` = `secciones`.`id` 
                left join `categorias` on `secciones`.`id_Categoria` = `categorias`.`id` 
                 
                where 
                    `productos`.`activo` = 1 and
                    `productos`.`descuento` > 0 
                GROUP by ofertas_expirables.sku_producto
```

intentado arreglar el problema, me di cuenta que se provoca cuando ambos join a las tablas ***sku_producto*** y ***detalle_ordencompra*** se encuentran juntos se provoca el problema, si quito uno, el sum calcula bien, pero no tengo acceso para hacer el segundo sum

agrego el siguiente [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sPue9vx13pVgdSmiRt1U37/4) para que puedan verificar la consulta

Comment: Prueba agregar la otra columna al `GROUP BY`, algo así: **`GROUP by ofertas_expirables.sku_producto, detalle_ordencompra.sku_producto`**

Comment: Lo intente y sigue calculando mal el sum

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que lo sigue calcluando mal, a que arroja ahora un resultado erróneo? El problema inicial era que duplicaba las filas ¿no? Si ahora te muestra una sola fila pero con una suma que no es correcta, puede que el error esté en los datos o en la forma en que las tablas se relacionan. Conviene siempre en preguntas sobre bases de datos que pongas un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable y un fiddle para poder analizar el modelo de datos y hacer pruebas.

Comment: agregue un fiddle y en la parte de la consulta hago una pequeña aclaracion de lo que necesito que haga

Comment: A ver, según lo que comentas en el fiddle, quieres filtrar por la columna `estado` de la tabla `ordencompra`, entonces, tienes que incorporar esa tabla en la consulta con algo como esto: **`left join ordencompra on detalle_ordencompra.id = ordencompra.id`**  y luego en la parte del `where` agregar esto: **`and ordencompra.estado='pago confirmado'`** De todos modos, veo todo muy lioso y explicado con poca claridad. Yo te aconsejaría que escribas una consulta lo más simple posible en la que puedas ver los resultados esperados y que partiendo de ella empieces a agregar otras tablas en los join.

Comment: Digo esto porque incorporando lo dicho en el fiddle no hay ninguna coincidencia en esa consulta. Para probar yo intenté mostrar la columna `estado` y en las dos filas me sale `null`, por tanto, como te dije en otro comentario, o hay un error en tus datos o en el diseño. La mejor forma de hacer esto es escribiendo la consulta más básica (la que daría la suma correcta) y luego ir agregando las tablas de los join una por una y probando ... cuando la consulta empiece a fallar sabrás que el fallo estaría en esa tabla que acabaste de incorporar a la consulta.

Comment: Poniendo en práctica la técnica de discrimnación que te he sugerido, se puede ver claramente que los problemas empiezan cuando incorporas este join: `left join stock_productos as sp on ofertas_expirables.sku_producto = sp.sku_producto`. Es partir de ese join cuando la suma comienza a dar `12` en vez de `6` por tanto, deberías revisar qué pasa con los datos en esa tabla o determinar si estás haciendo el join correctamente en ella.

Comment: estoy intentando hacer el sum que proviene de la tabla detalle_ordencompra con un case, no he logrado mucho, pero actualize el fiddle.

Comment: Pero el problema no es ese sino que la forma en que haces los join (o lo datos) está mal. ¿Leíste y entendiste lo que quise decirte en mi último comentario?

Comment: si entendi, pero hize la pregunta porque no pude darle yo la solución

Comment: No entendí... ni lo que comentas sobre el `case` ni la solución a la que te refieres. ¿Ya resolviste el problema? ¿Revisaste el asunto del join y los datos en la tabla `stock_productos`? ¿A qué conclusión llegaste?

Comment: intente con varios tipos de join, right, full, outer, etc y ninguno soluciona el tema es que si hago join a ambas tablas duplique el valor de los sums, respecto al case, en el fiddle actualize a lo que estoy tratando de hacer que cuando se de el caso que el estado de la tabla ordencompra sea pagado, sume la cantidad de la tabla detalle_ordencompra en caso de que no sea ese el estado, darle valor de 0 a la row que esta iterando

Comment: Creo que no has entendido lo que te quiero decir. Ya te indiqué el join problemático, que es este: `left join stock_productos as sp on ofertas_expirables.sku_producto = sp.sku_producto` significa que: 1. O no debe hacerse join por esas columnas o 2. Los datos no son correctos en esa tabla ... casi siempre el problema es lo mencionado en 2... Entonces: **revisa los datos que tienes en la tabla `stock_productos`** Si el problema son los datos no se trata de recurrir a trucos para que una consulta funcione, sino que **hay que corregir los datos**.

Comment: la version que subi al fiddle es una version con menos registros que mi base de datos, para que pudieras verificar, respecto a lo de verificar los datos, ambos son correctos, revisandolos columna por columna no hay ninguna discrepancia a lo que esperaba que almaceran, el tema de la duplicidad se produce porque tanto en la tabla detalle_ordencompra y stock_productos, el sku se encuentra presente en mas de una row, actualmente la tabla stock_productos contiene 2 registros con el primer sku que retorna la consulta y 2 del segundo, la tabla detalle_ordencompra tiene 2 registros con el primer sku

Comment: y uno con el segundo, por lo que supongo que como ambas pueden tener mas de un registro debe estar trayendo 2 por cada una y duplicando el valor de los sums

Comment: Los `GROUP BY` sirven para que no se repitan filas en aquellas columnas que indicas en la agrupación. Como ya dije, si debes obtener una suma de 6 y obtienes 12 y eso se produce cuando incorporas una determinada tabla, entonces debes verificar lo que está ocurriendo en los datos de esa tabla.

Comment: Te recomiendo que para casos complejos como este crees un ejemplo lo más sencillo posible, únicamente con las tablas problemáticas y con la menor cantidad posible de columnas. Así podrás probar los datos con mayor claridad, toda la cuestión del `CASE`  que agregaste posteriormente solamente arroja más confusión en las consultas, aparte de ser un *truco* que no servirá para resolver un problema que está en los datos o en el diseño de las tablas.